# How to bundle d3 v4 using webpack

Tags: d3.js, webpack

I was using D3 v3 with webpack which was simple with one single package. Now that **D3 v4** has become modular with separate packages, I am unable to bundle them into single package.

I have referred to mbostock's [article](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4) below using rollup but it fails saying it is unable to load d3 from index.js. Can anyone help me with how to bundle them using webpack?

**EDIT 1:**
I removed d3 from the rollup options and the rollup worked fine. I have explained the steps below

1. D3 v4 installed.
2. Added rollup config and storing to ./dist/d3.min.js
3. pointed webpack to the ./dist/d3.min.js
4. tried **resolve.alias** in webpack and require("d3") in one home.js. But no luck it says

> cannot resolve module d3 in home.js

5. tried **webpack.Provideplugin** in home.js. Still the above error.

Can anyone please help me with getting this d3 loaded?

**Rollup.js**

```
import node from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";

export default {
  entry: "index.js",
  format: "umd",
  moduleName: "d3",
  plugins: [node()],
  dest: "./dist/d3.js"
};
```

**index.js**

```
export * from "d3-selection";
export * from "d3-zoom";
export * from "d3-scale";
export * from "d3-drag";
export * from "d3-force";
export * from "d3-axis";
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {

        entry:    [
            //"./dist/d3-combined.js",
            "./client/home.js"
            ,"./client/pages.js"
            ,"./client/graph.js"
            ,"./client/orient_databases.js"
            ,"./node_modules/d3/d3.js",
            ,"./public/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"

        ]
        ,output: { 
            path: path.join(__dirname,'dist')
          // ,path: '/static'
            ,publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/scripts/'
            ,filename: 'bundle.js'
        }
        ,plugins :[
              new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    jquery : "jquery"
                }),  

           new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
              compress: {
                warnings: false
              }
            })
        ]
        ,module: {
            // avoid webpack trying to shim process
            noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/,
            loaders: [
              {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue'
              },
              {
                test: /\.js$/,
                // excluding some local linked packages.
                // for normal use cases only node_modules is needed.
                exclude: /node_modules|vue\/dist|vue-router\/|vue-loader\/|vue-hot-reload-api\//,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query : {
                    presets : ['es2015']
                    //,optional : ["runtime"]
                }
              }
            ]
          }

         ,resolve : {
            //root : [path.resolve('./node_modules')],
            alias : [ {"d3": path.join(__dirname,"dist/d3.min.js") } ],
            modulesDirectories : ["node_modules"]
         }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using rollup with Webpack??

Comment: I am using rollup to bundle the specific d3 modules (like d3-selection, d3-scale etc.) as d3. Technically it is not needed if we are using the complete d3 module.

Comment: you want only specific modules into your webpack bundle?

Comment: Not needed now. But I thought it would be a best practice to do so to keep the asset size optimal. Wondering where is this failing? Even strange is that even after installing d3 module and using webpack.Providenewplugin also the d3 module is not being resolved!

Answer (score 1):

There are [quite a few](http://alex-r-bigelow.github.io/#D3andBabel) incompatibilities with D3 v4's rollup approach and webpack—yours is totally a sensible approach.

It looks like you're missing the minification step? (Rollup.js creates `d3.js`, but webpack.config.js expects `d3.min.js`)

It's also possible that webpack v2's new configuration has some relevant fixes.

This setup works for me (using webpack v2):

#### home.js

`let d3 = require('d3');`

#### rollup.config.js

```
import npm from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  entry: './d3.bundle.js',
  format: 'umd',
  moduleName: 'd3',
  plugins: [npm({jsnext: true})],
  dest: './dist/d3.js'
};
```

#### d3.bundle.js

```
export * from "d3-selection";
export * from "d3-zoom";
export * from "d3-scale";
export * from "d3-drag";
export * from "d3-force";
export * from "d3-axis";
```

#### package.json

```
{

  ...

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "rollup -c && uglifyjs dist/d3.js -c -m -o dist/d3.min.js"
  },

  ...
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {

  ...

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'd3': path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/d3.min.js')
    }
  },

  ...

};
```